# Python TypeError : Descriptor 'append' for 'bytearray' objects does't apply to a list object

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe

I have a str list and I am trying to append the list elements into a bytearray. The goal is to compare this bytearray with another bytearray using a different function but I am stuck with this type error.

```
frame_cols = [frames['value'] for idx, frames in frames.iterrows()] #list from a df

frame_per_offset = bytearray.append(frame_cols) #error occurs here
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending you should set source argument in bytearray.

```
frame_per_offset = bytearray(frame_cols)
```

Comment: I tried this way as passing an argument. I am getting an error since the list elements are in 'str' and I had to encode like this  

'''frame_per_offset = bytearray(str(frame_cols),encoding='utf-8')'''